# MVC 5 select from 2 model linq expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example i have 2 model.

ASpnetUserRoles and ASPnetRoles

i want to select ASPnetRoles.Name,ASPnetROles.ID where ASPnetRoles.ID in ASPnetUserRoles.

i only know how to write in SQL

```
select * from modalA where modelA.id in(select modelB.id from modelB)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you enable "[Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1)" , you can use this linq query :

```
using(var db = ..."context"..)
{
   var q = db.AspNetUserRoles.where(c=>c.UserID = userIdVal)
                             .select(z=> new { RoleId = z.RoleId
                                              ,userId = z.UserId
                                              ,RoleName = z.AspNetRole.RoleName
                                             })
                             .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did eventually.

```
 IEnumerable<IdentityRole> ro;
        ro = (from p in haha join ur in aspNetUser.AspNetRoles on p.Id equals ur.Id select p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a generic sample you  must create a class (no EF), and store the result to it.

```
IQueryable<ResultClass> result=from t1 in db.Table1
                                 join t2 in db.Table2
                                 //Here the relation fields
                                 on t1.IdTable1 equals t2.IdTable2
                                 //Here where conditios and/or orderby
                                 select new ResultClass()
                                 {
                                     Field1=t1.SomeField,
                                     Field2=t2.SomeField,
                                     //all need fields
                                 }
```

Use the result

```
result.ToList()
```